# How do I call archive.tar in salt?

Tags: tar, salt-stack

I'm trying to untar a file in a salt state file. This is the relevant state:

```
install-file:
#unpack
  archive.tar:
    - options: xjf
    - tarfile: /opt/path/to/file.tar.bz
    - dest: /opt/path/to/
    - watch:
      - file: /opt/path/to/file.tar.bz
#get files
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://pkgs/path/to/file.tar.bz
    - name: /opt/path/to/file.tar.bz
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
    State: - archive
    Name:      install-sdk
    Function:  tar
        Result:    False
        Comment:   State archive.tar found in sls pkgs.android is unavailable
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty sure it's not a versioning issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main issue here is that there is no `archive.tar` state. The reason for that is probably misunderstanding of so-called modules and states. The `archive` is module with some functions you can call from cli like:

```
salt '*' archive.tar cjvf /tmp/tarfile.tar.bz2 /tmp/file_1,/tmp/file_2
```

Now there is a way to actually use the module from your states. There is a `module.run` state to do just that. I made a quick example with the `archive.tar` call:

```
untar_file:
  module.run:
    - name: archive.tar
    - options: xjf
    - tarfile: /opt/path/to/file.tar.bz 
    - dest: /opt/path/to/
```

The -name parameter specifies which module and function to run, the other parameters are passed to the actual function.

You can find additional parameters that are passed to the tar function here:
http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.archive.html#salt.modules.archive.tar

Answer (score 0):

Actually: The states.archive is completely missing from the 0.17.x tarballs!

```
markizano@localhost:/tmp/salt$for tar in *; do tar --list -f $tar; done|sort|grep archive.py
salt-0.16.0/salt/modules/archive.py
salt-0.17.0/salt/modules/archive.py
salt-0.17.1/salt/modules/archive.py
salt-0.17.2/salt/modules/archive.py
salt-0.17.3/salt/modules/archive.py
salt-0.17.4/salt/modules/archive.py
salt-0.17.5/salt/modules/archive.py
salt-2014.1.0/salt/modules/archive.py
salt-2014.1.0/salt/states/archive.py
```

Upgrade to the latest version to have access to archive.extracted in your states.
As a hotfix, you can copy the develop branch of the github into

```
{{ salt['grains.get']('saltpath') }}/states/archive.py
```

Restart saltmaster/saltminion after an update like this.

SaltDocs: http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/all/salt.states.archive.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this message, and you're working with a windows minion, and the release you're using is earlier than 2015.2, it's telling the truth. It's not available. See https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/12992.